# Information about the Belz yeshiva in Jerusalem

Tags: yeshiva-school, yerushalayim-jerusalem

I'm looking for an english yeshiva in Jerusalem geared towards baalei teshuvah and I have heard about the Belz yeshiva in Jerusalem. I have been unable to find any information about it, however. Does anyone have any information about it, in particular if it's an english yeshiva?

Comment: @JacobL Torah VeEmunah is in Geulah but not English, Belz run for Israeli BT

Comment: Go to Ohr Samayach in Yerushalayim. My father went there, its a very good place.

Comment: for an English speaking baal teshuva yeshiva maayanot is the place to go. I have many good friends who went there.

Comment: I second Kovy Jacobs, you can watch many Ohr Somaych lectures online too to get a feel for the atmosphere, a little different than other yeshivas. Some of the greatest Rabbis out there.


Rabbi Gottlieb: https://www.torahanytime.com/#/speaker?l=32


Rabbi Breowitz: https://www.torahanytime.com/#/speaker?l=414


Rabbi Kaplan: https://www.torahanytime.com/#/speaker?l=36

Answer (score 5):

It's called Torah v'emunah and is located in Zichron Moshe. On Moshe Khagiz St. A block from Mayanot, the Chabad place. I believe it's primarily  Hebrew language but there's a chaburah in English. Here's the Belz website for contacting them:  https://worldofbelz.org/avodah/

Answer (score 0):

I searched the [Olam Hatorah site](http://www.torahindex.com/en/inst/default.aspx?index=1&name=belz&page=1) for Belz Yeshivas and did not find one specifically for Baalei Teshuva.

26 institutions come up when I search for Yeshivas for [Baalei Teshuva in Jerusalem](http://www.torahindex.com/en/inst/default.aspx?index=1&city=Jerusalem%20%20%20&subcat=26). I suggest you investigate them.